# Odoo8. Upload product image programmatically

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I get an image from url and try to upload it to Odoo (product.template, image column). I tried many methods to do that but none of them helped me. Could you give me the right way to upload image of product to Odoo without using csv import.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
import urllib2
import base64

image = urllib2.urlopen('http://ddd.com/somepics.jpg').read()

image_base64 = base64.encodestring(image)

product.image_medium = image_base64    //(new api v9)

#in old api maybe something like 

#prod_obj.write(prod_id, {'image_medium': image_base64})
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need something like this 
using a psycopg2 library

```
try:
    logo = urllib2.urlopen(logo_url).read()
    except:
            print 'waitting 60s'
            time.sleep(60)
            logo = urllib2.urlopen(logo_url).read()
            res_data={'image':psycopg2.Binary(logo)}
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have image URL and need to set in product then you can do as following and call this method when install/upgrade your custom module.

```
import requests
import base64

    @api.multi
    def get_image(self):
        for product in self:
            img = False
            if image.url:
                response = requests.get(image.url)
                if response.ok and response.content : 
                    img = base64.b64encode(response.content)
                else :
                    img = False
            product.image = img
```